# Manage Java processes using control groups

Tags: java, linux, process, process-management

Does anybody has already used Linux Control Groups (cgroup) to manage Java processes? I'm trying to profile CPU time utilization (thanks to the cpuacct.usage file) and I'm unable to get other value than 0...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to get process CPU time utilization, informations contained into the procfs file system could be useful. See `/proc/[pid]/stat` under a standard Linux system for more details (`man proc`)

Between, I'm still waiting for a clue to my cgroup "mistake" :)

Answer (score -1):

Use jcgroup please. https://github.com/haosdent/jcgroup You could use this library to limit the CPU shares, Disk I/O speed, Network bandwidth and etc.